# Select all tables which begin with "coc"

Tags: select

Select all tables which begin with "coc"
I wanna know how to select all tables which begin with "coc". There are coc1, coc2, coc3.... tables in DB.

```
SELECT * FROM coc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM coc1
 UNION
SELECT *
  FROM coc2
 UNION
SELECT *
  FROM coc3
```

or

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME
  FROM
    information_schema.TABLES 
 WHERE
    table_schema = [DB_NAME]
   AND
    TABLE_NAME LIKE 'coc%'
```